# Mapbox Directions causes stacks to collapse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I created my map using react and JS following the directions given by Mapbox here: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/. Everything went well until I attempted to add directions, then I received the errors below. Is this the proper way to add the direction plugin?

I used the code here on mapbox: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-directions/.

[image: Error message]

[image]

[image]

Comment: show where `MapboxDirections` is imported

Comment: added image to show imports

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions. Install and import from `@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions`

Comment: fails to compile : ./src/index.js
Attempted import error: '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions' does not contain a default export (imported as 'MapboxDirections').

Comment: Sorry about that, the repo looks to be broken by looking at the Issues.

Comment: I thank you for your help regardless.